# React Router 6: new useRoutes() method -> how to define a 'redirect'?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Using the new React Router 6, I prefer using the [Route Objects](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/examples/route-objects#route-objects-example) method (using `useRoutes()`) over the normal JSX route definitions.

I want to redirect from '/' to '/login'. The docs do not mention though how to achieve such a redirect. Below are my current routes. What am I missing here?

```
const routes = [
  { path: '/', element: <Login /> },
  { path: 'login', element: <Login /> },
  { path: 'test', element: <Test /> },
  { path: 'chat', element: <Chat /> },
  { path: '*', element: <NotFound /> },
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `<Navigate to="/login" />` as element for `/` path.

```
const routes = [
  { path: '/', element: <Navigate to="/login" /> },
  { path: 'login', element: <Login /> },
  { path: 'test', element: <Test /> },
  { path: 'chat', element: <Chat /> },
  { path: '*', element: <NotFound /> },
];
```

Check this link. I have edited their official example and added a redirect from `/login` to `/`. You can navigate across links using links present in the lower half of the UI.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-xlvehj?file=src/App.tsx

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot. I didn't realize you can simply put `<Navigate>` in the 'element' attribute.